# ScrollViewer is not working for TextBlock in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Friends, below is my code. I don't know why my scroll bar is not working.

```
<Window x:Class="Seris.Views.Help"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Help" Height="400" Width="400">
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="350" Width="372"><InlineUIContainer>
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="1.37,0.46" Source="../Images/help.jpg"/>
                </InlineUIContainer><Run/><LineBreak/><Run Text="There are some validations on the Vehicle Form as below."/><LineBreak/><Run Text="P"/><Run Text="lease note that all the fields are mandatory."/><LineBreak/><Run/><LineBreak/><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Vehicle No"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="It should be always 7 character long con"/><Run Text="taining "/><Run Text="first 3 digits as alphabet in capital form and remaining 4 numerical. "/><LineBreak/><Run Text="i.e. GHI1234"/><LineBreak/><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Model"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="It can be anything except null."/><LineBreak/><Run Text="i.e. Fluid"/><LineBreak/><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Manufacturing Date"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="It should not be a future date."/><LineBreak/><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="IU No"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="It must be 10 digit numerical number."/><LineBreak/><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Personnel Name"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="You must select Personnel Name from combo box."/><LineBreak/>
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Height="350"` & `Width="372"` from the TextBlock, these are preventing ScrollViewer to work properly

if you want to restrict the size you may apply the same to DockPanel or ScrollViewer as needed.

so in short if you apply width or height to TextBlock that will restrict the size of the element and ScrollViewer may not work as expected.

additionally you may also remove `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` & `VerticalAlignment="Top"` from the TextBlock as they might not be required as well